# How to properly run heavy calculations in Parallel using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, asynchronous, parallel-processing

### The Goal

The goal is to compute all possible polyform shapes of a certain number of squares. Since this is very heavy computation for larger number I wanted to make use of the multiple cores that my computer has.

### The Problem

I made the problem easier to explain and test by creating the following scenario:

```
1) for each value of 2, 3, 5, and 7:
2) find all multiples (up to a certain value) and add them to the same List
3) remove all duplicates from said list
```

In my final program step 2 is much more vast and computationally heavy, and thus I would prefer to split task two in however many values I want to check based on the values of step 1.

### What I Tried

I made a winforms app with C# Core with 5 button trying different variations of parallelism that I found here on Stackoverflow and other places on the internet:
[image]

Here is the code (which looks like a lot, but it's just 5 variations of the same idea), they all give a count to check if they produced the same result + what time it took:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Parallelism
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly int Repeat = 10000000; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            foreach (int x in new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 })
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
                {
                    output.Add(x * i);
                }
            }
            output = output.Distinct().ToList();
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ConcurrentBag<int> output = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            Task task = Task.WhenAll(
              Task.Run(() => button2_Calculation(2, output)),
              Task.Run(() => button2_Calculation(3, output)),
              Task.Run(() => button2_Calculation(5, output)),
              Task.Run(() => button2_Calculation(7, output))
            );
            task.Wait();
            HashSet<int> output2 = new HashSet<int>(output);
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output2.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }
        private void button2_Calculation(int x, ConcurrentBag<int> output)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
            {
                output.Add(x * i);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            foreach (int x in (new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 }).AsParallel())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
                {
                    output.Add(x * i);
                }
            }
            output = output.Distinct().ToList();
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ConcurrentBag<int> output = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            Dictionary<int, Task> runningTasks = new Dictionary<int, Task>();
            foreach (int x in new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 })
            {
                int value = x;
                runningTasks.Add(x, Task.Factory.StartNew(() => button2_Calculation(value, output)));
            }
            foreach (Task t in runningTasks.Select(c => c.Value))
                t.Wait();
            HashSet<int> output2 = new HashSet<int>(output);
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output2.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ConcurrentBag<int> output = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            Parallel.ForEach(new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 }, x => button5_Calculation(x, output));
            HashSet<int> output2 = new HashSet<int>(output);
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output2.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }
        private void button5_Calculation(int x, ConcurrentBag<int> output)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
                output.Add(x * i);
        }
    }
}
```

### Results So Far

So far all the above methods result in a similar duration between 1s - 1.5s.
Actually, sometimes the normal serial executions seems to be a lot faster.
How is this possible? I would expect that with 8 cores (16 virtual cores) that splitting the tasks would result in a faster overal speed?

Any help is very much appreciated!

### The future

After learning more about how to properly implement parallelism I expect to also run the entirety of the calculations on another thread / Async to allow the GUI to remain responsive.

#### EDIT:

Response to @Pac0:
Here is my implementation of your suggestions. It doesn't seem to make much difference:
[image]

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ConcurrentBag<HashSet<int>> bag = new ConcurrentBag<HashSet<int>>();
            var output = Parallel.ForEach(new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 }, x =>
            {
                HashSet<int> temp = new HashSet<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
                    temp.Add(x * i);
                bag.Add(temp);
            });
            HashSet<int> output2 = new HashSet<int>();
            foreach (var hash in bag)
                output2.UnionWith(hash);
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output2.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }
```

Comment: Can you try the same methods for `Repeat = 100000000` and see the results?

Comment: My guess is that since you always use the same approach with a concurrentbag to store results "on the fly", you cause a lots of locking, hence losing the benefit of using many threads. But I maybe mistaken since I don't use concurrentbag for large storage.
I would go more for a "Map / Reduce" approach : do the calculations for 2, 3, 5, and 7 independently, then "merge" all the results.

Comment: so basically, create a `HashSet` per parallel calculation, then once all are done, do a Union of the hashsets (that will take care of duplicates).

Comment: Tasks/async is generally only for I/O bound code, which yours isn't.

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty, Here are the results for 100.000.000x: https://i.imgur.com/luahcSv.png as you can see there is some difference and method 2 seems to be only 20% faster even though there are 4 seperate threads.

Comment: @Neil it's also well suited for CPU bound heavy work, when you have a mainthread (like a GUI) that you don't want to freeze.

Comment: @Pac0 I edited my main question to show my implementation of your suggestion.

Comment: You seem to be operating under the assumption that the bottle neck is the `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)`. How have you confirmed that the problem is there, and not with the code which removes duplicates?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson , you are correct. In this example the biggest bottleneck is the removal of duplicates. This is however different in the actual implementation of my code. But I will take suggestion on making the duplicate removal more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment mentioned your use of a single collection is causing significant locking.  Computationally a task based solution is about 50% faster (see below where we don't manage a combined output).  Its managing the collection that's causing some binding.  Depending on how its handled it can be upwards of 3 times slower than serial execution.

The struggle with concurrency is always balancing the load to the bottleneck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Repeat = 100000000;
        static int[] worklist = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! Launching Threads");
            Task launcher = Task.Run(()=>LaunchThreads());
            launcher.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World! Threads Complete");

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Threads took: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

            watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine("Serial Execution Starting");
            foreach (int i in worklist)
            {
                DoWork(i);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Serial Execution took: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
        static async void LaunchThreads()
        {
            //Dictionary<int, List<int>> mywork = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
            HashSet<int> output = new HashSet<int>();

            var worktasks = new List<Task<List<int>>>();

            foreach (int i in worklist)
            {
                worktasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork(i)));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(worktasks);
        }
        static List<int> DoWork(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread Worker: {x}");
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
            {
                output.Add(x * i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread Worker: {x} - Exiting");
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add I tried using an IProgress based feedback to add the items to the hashset directly, but that was the worst of the bunch.  Iterating over the results and UnionWith on the hashset seemed to be the best, but was still slow.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this as an awnser because someone named Yugami posted something that was different from what I tried and it was a useful and good response, but it was deleted.

So I am posting my efforts at recreating their code in my test bench:

```
private async void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            HashSet<int> output = new HashSet<int>();
            var worktasks = new List<Task<List<int>>>();
            foreach (int i in new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 })
                worktasks.Add(Task.Run(() => button9_Calculation(i)));

            await Task.WhenAll(worktasks);
            foreach (Task<List<int>> tsk in worktasks)
                foreach (int i in tsk.Result)
                    output.Add(i);
            watch.Stop();
            (sender as Button).Text += $", c:{output.Count} - {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms";
        }
        private List<int> button9_Calculation(int x)
        {
            List<int> output = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Repeat; i++)
                output.Add(x * i);

            return output;
        }
```

Here are the results of the serial and best two solutions with 100.000.000 tries.
Here I finally see some improvement of doing step 2 in parallel, but now the biggest bottleneck is removing the duplicates / filtering it all down to a single HashSet...
[image]

So I think this solves the initial question that I had to improve step 2.
Now I will continue my search to improve on Step 3; removing the duplicates.

Comment: Sorry my solution was not complete, but only noticed it after the fact.  I've cleaned it up but theres still issues depending on how you want to deal with the data.

Comment: Just a note, in the method `button9_Calculation` you know that `output` will contain `Repeat` items, so you could construct it with `List<int> output = new List<int>(Repeat)`. It should perform a little better by eliminating the need to resize the list during the execution of the method.